# Is it possible to return a struct with references to mutable data in it in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership

I was making a little pseudo-game thing and wanted to create a function to return a generic enemy. For some reason it didn't allow me to include use of `[0, 0]`.
Here's the code:

```rust
struct Enemy<'a> {
    pos: &'a mut [i32; 2],// [0] = x, [1] = y
    veloc: &'a mut [i32; 2],// see `pos` property
    monstype: String,
    id: String
}

impl<'a> Enemy<'_> {
    pub fn new(monster_type: String) -> Enemy<'a> {
        Enemy {
            pos: &mut [0, 0],
            veloc: &mut [0, 0],
            monstype: monster_type,
            id: Enemy::generate_id(8)// unrelated, omitted from this code snippet
        }
    }
}
```

This, generates this error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src\main.rs:19:9
   |
19 | /         Enemy {
20 | |             pos: &mut [0, 0],
21 | |             veloc: &mut [0, 0],
   | |                         ------ temporary value created here
22 | |             monstype: monster_type,
23 | |             id: Enemy::generate_id(8)
24 | |         }
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src\main.rs:19:9
   |
19 | /         Enemy {
20 | |             pos: &mut [0, 0],
   | |                       ------ temporary value created here
21 | |             veloc: &mut [0, 0],
22 | |             monstype: monster_type,
23 | |             id: Enemy::generate_id(8)
24 | |         }
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I tried `.clone()` on the array but that of course doesn't work as the data is still temporary and owned by the function.

Comment: `struct Enemy<'a>` means "struct `Enemy` that borrows data from some value up the stack, denoted by `'a`." Who is `Enemy` returned by `Enemy::new()` borrowing from? Why not declare the `pos` field as just `pos: [i32; 2]`?

Comment: Do you mean constants or do you mean references to mutable data?

Comment: If you want instances of the struct to be mutable, you do this by declaring an instance `mut` and then using a `&mut Enemy`. You do not declare mutability within the struct definition itself.

Comment: *this, for some reason, generates this error* - The code fails to compile not for some obscure reason, but because it actually returns a reference to a local variable, and allowing it to compile would lead to corruption. `&mut [0, 0]` is syntactic sugar for declaring an invisible local `let mut tmp = [0, 0]` and using `&mut tmp`. That's super-useful when passing `&mut [0, 0]` to as arguments to functions you're calling ([downward-funargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/581182/1600898)), but is useless for use in values you're about to return.

Comment: note: `sizeof<&mut [i32;2]>()` and `sizeof<[i32;2]>()` is the same on most platforms, so you will not *"minimize RAM usage"* by using one over the other, instead, you'll add indirection, forcing the compiler to add more instructions and an additional memory location for the actual position, doing the exact opposite of your stated goal.

Comment: @possum I mean references to mutable data, thanks for the clarification
@BallpointBen I forgot about the ability to declare things as `let mut x = ..` instead of returning mutable references thanks
@cafce25 thanks, that makes sense combined with the comment clarifying syntactic sugar

Comment: @user4815162342 `Enemy::new()` is borrowing from main as that is the only place that it is called from. declaring `pos` as `pos: [i32; 2]`  makes sense, because we declare `enemy` as mutable, thank you!

Comment: `Enemy::new` takes one argument by value and none by reference. I don't think it's *borrowing* from anything. It's being *called* from `main`, but that's not the same thing as borrowing. I really don't think your `Enemy` struct has any reason to use references.

Comment: @synnøve In Rust, "borrowing" has a narrow technical meaning. A reference borrows data from someone who ultimately owns it, and is defined in one of the callers up the stack. You can't just "borrow from main", you have to borrow from a _value_ defined in `main()`. Since `new()` doesn't receive reference to such a value, it can't and doesn't borrow from `main()`. My question was intended to nudge you into realizing that a reference in `Enemy` doesn't work in how you're using that type. (I'd also add that it doesn't make things more efficient, either, on the contrary.)

Comment: If you want to reference the same data for some reason in multiple structs, which is not visible in your sample, Rust has the concept of reference counting ([Rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably looking for

```
struct Enemy {
    pos: [i32; 2],
    veloc: [i32; 2],
    monstype: String,
    id: String,
}
```

There's no reason (at least, no reason in the snippet you've shown) for `Enemy` to be *borrowing* anything, so we can cut out the lifetime parameter `'a` and all of the borrow complexity and just return arrays. Arrays are perfectly valid sized data-types and can be returned as part of a struct.

If you *don't* know the size in advance, you can use `Vec`.

```
struct Enemy {
    pos: Vec<i32>,
    veloc: Vec<i32>,
    monstype: String,
    id: String,
}
```

Then you can construct these using the ever-helpful `vec` macro.

```
Enemy {
  pos: vec![0, 0],
  veloc: vec![0, 0],
  monstype: String::from("Whatever"),
  id: String::from("0"),
}
```

Finally, if your arrays are large and you have good reason to be worried about passing them by value, then you can add indirection not with `&mut` (which is for borrows) but with `Box`. I *do not* recommend doing this unless you have very good reason to. The extra indirection is very likely to slow your program down in most cases. But you *can* do

```
struct Enemy {
    pos: Box<[i32; 2]>,
    veloc: Box<[i32; 2]>,
    monstype: String,
    id: String,
}
```

Then construct as

```
Enemy {
  pos: Box::new([0, 0]),
  veloc: Box::new([0, 0]),
  monstype: String::from("Whatever"),
  id: String::from("0"),
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The error still says that the function returns data owned by the current function, is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Can you add your current code to the original post as an edit? There's nothing in the snippet I provided that borrows anything so you shouldn't be seeing that error anymore. Did you remove the unused `<'a>` lifetime parameter?

Comment: `struct Enemy {
    pos: [i32; 2]
    veloc: [i32; 2],
    monstype: String,
    id: String
}

impl Enemy {
    pub fn new(monster_type: String, zeroized_array: &mut [i32; 2]) -> &mut Enemy {
        &mut Enemy {
            pos: *zeroized_array,
            veloc: *zeroized_array,
            monstype: monster_type,
            id: Enemy::generate_id(8)
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut bind = [0, 0];
    let enemy: &mut Enemy = Enemy::new("zombie".to_string(), &mut bind);
`}`
(omitted some code for readability, apologies for horrid formatting)

Comment: Just take `zeroized_array` by value too. Remove the `&mut` on both the parameter and at the call site. There's no need to borrow *anything* here.